# Set uploaded photo as website background image

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, css

I wrote a very simple image upload script, after uploading the image I thought of making the background of the linking screen the uploaded image but i have no idea how to do it or i dont know if it can be done. Can anyone help me?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kV83k.jpg)

Comment: Please may you add a [mcve] of the issue?

Comment: when i uplaod any image on website(zafernci.xyz/uploadd) set my uploaded photo as background image. 
is that clear to you?

Comment: That's a requirement, not a problem or question. We're not a free write-my-code service. Research, attempt, and then ask here if you have some code and/or a _specific_ issue. Https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: P.s. hint: CSS can set background images

Comment: already i'm asking that question.. my question is possible?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. You have to save the uploaded image in the server and then set it as background by JavaScript or CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use following code

```js
function change_img(){
var img_url = document.getElementById("url").value;
document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style.backgroundImage = "url('"+img_url+"')";
}
```

```html
    <input type="url" name="" id="url" placeholder="Enter img url here">
    <button onclick="change_img()">change background</button>
```

First make a variable `img_url` and store url of image in it 
Then use `getElementsByTagName("body")[0]` this selects the body tag and then use `backgroungImage` to set background image.
Remember in css we use `background-image:url("image url")` to set bacground using js
So use `" url(' " + img_url + " ') "`

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: ty buddy, working <3

Comment: @NicoHaase I have added explaination you can see it